# python requests loading big page solution

Tags: python, parsing, url, get, python-requests

I have this trouble when opening a big page about 82,000 lines with Python requests lib. Before I tried to use urllib2, but here was an error "IncompleteRead"

Now with requests:

```
 r = requests.get(https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Model+Year_2016&Ns=p_PRICE_2|0&ci=13223&ipp=120&N=4110474291+4294948825+3665082495)
 page_source = r.content
 print page_source
```

The result of source print is not full, I see the end tag, but not from start of the document!

Have you any idea, how to load full content of this URL? 82000 lines.

Comment: This is probably only a limitation of the shell you are using. Try to save `page_source` to a file.

Comment: But why I can see only the end part of the source code ?

Comment: Because most shell have a buffer limit. Only `X` amount of characters can be displayed at once, so obviously these will be the **last** `X` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Most (if not all) shells have a characters limit. Saving `page_source` to a file confirms that `requests.get` returns the whole page:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Model+Year_2016&Ns=p_PRICE_2|0&ci=13223&ipp=120&N=4110474291+4294948825+3665082495')
page_source = r.text
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(page_source.strip())
```

The file contents starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` which is the start of the page.
Also note I'm using `.text` instead of `.content` to get a cleaner representation of the page source. I also used `.strip()` because this page's source starts with useless `'\n'` for some reason.

Another approach would be to simply print the first 100 (or whatever) characters of `page_source`:

```
print(page_source[:100])
# <!DOCTYPE html>
# <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
# <!--[if IE 7]>
```